# Cannot resolve symbol BitmapFactory.decodeResource in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, bitmapfactory

I try to use method decodeResource from class BitmapFactory in my Activity like this:

```
Bitmap image = new BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.my_image);
```

I made all necessary imports, IntelliJ even completes method for me as I am type it but as I try to compile it gives me error:

```
java: cannot find symbol

symbol:   class decodeResource 

location: class android.graphics.BitmapFactory
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `new`, because `decodeResource` is static method,

Use like this

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.my_image);
```